# remove all files and folders not listed in file

Tags: bash, shell-script, file-management

I am looking into a way of deleting all files and folders recursively in the current working directory that are **not listed** in  `files2keep.txt`. I am using Linux.

The text file can be quite large, up to several GB in size with multi-million rows.
Files in the text file are relative to the current working directory, for example:

```
Dummy_Path_001/00110-003/VET_Visit2/VET/PTCT-PET_AC_FOOT-604/1/2021-06-22T18-45-00.766Z
Dummy_Path_001/00110-003/VET_Visit2/VET/PTCT-PET_AC_FOOT-607/1/2021-06-22T18-44-55.904Z
Dummy_Path_001/00110-003/VET_Visit2/VET/PTCT-PET_AC_FOOT-610/1/2021-06-22T18-44-57.682Z
```

Using rsync is one of the options, but would lead to some initial data duplication and probably disk space issues.

There will be no whitespace in the file names or paths.

All ideas are welcome

Comment: How are the files listed? Just the name or the path? If a path, is it a relative path or an absolute one? What are your file names like? Do we need to deal with _anything_ or can you at least ensure there will be no newline characters in the file names? How about spaces?

Comment: Where have *"looking into"* brought you? What is your idea / thought on how to proceed?

Comment: @terdon files are listed with relative paths, no spaces or new line characters in the files names. Added an example to the question.

Comment: OK, I added that to your question because if we can be _sure_ there will be no whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines etc) in the file names, that makes things simpler.

Comment: (1) What if `foo/bar` is listed but `foo` is not listed? According to the rule `foo/bar` should survive but `foo` should be deleted. Can such situation happen in the file? What to do then? (2) Can `.` or `..` pathname component appear in the file? Can `//` substring appear? (3) Are directories listed without a trailing `/`? Can we count on this? (4) Can there be symlinks in the tree? If a symlink to a directory, should we follow it and descend further from the directory, testing the logical path against the file? If some symlink is not in the file, should we delete the symlink only?

Comment: presumably `files2keep.txt` will also be deleted during this process?

Comment: To rephrase some of the above, how should directories be handled? Under Unix filesystems, directories are still... files. What about other approaches? For example, moving the files to keep to another location (with or without partial path prefixes?), and simply deleting anything remaining, or any of the other approaches? Give more detail on what you want and searched for.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  Ideally, you'd keep the entire `files2keep.txt` in memory, rather than repeatedly grepping it.   Or convert it to a fast key-value store (with the pathnames as keys, and anything as the value as we only care about whether the keys exists or not) - e.g. use `tie` in perl to tie a hash to a BerkeleyDB or DBM file or something.  or berkeleydb bindings for python or your preferred language.  1. read files2keep.txt and populate the hash/associative array/dict/etc 2. recurse the directory tree - if file is not in hash, delete it.

Comment: Using some sort of db file is probably the best option.  That allows you to separate the job into two scripts - the first to read the text file and populate the db (which will take a significant amount of time for a multi-GB text file with millions of rows) and the second to actually delete files that aren't in it.  Writing and testing the second script will be faster (because the db is already populated, saving minutes at least per test run) and safer (because it can be written as a dry-run until you're sure it works how you want).

Comment: @cas 32GB of RAM and 8 CPU cores are available but can double both easily